# Life expectancy of electronic parts in old electronic keyboard

Tags: lifetime, vintage

I have an old Roland A80 keyboard, that was probably built in the late 80's or early 90's. And right now it works well. But I'm wondering, how long can I expect the electronic parts to keep working? It's been stored most of its life.

edit: I was asking this, mainly to figure out if I could fix this keyboard if any of the old electronics go bad. And rocketman412 said I should be able to find new chips, so that solves my problem. So I'll mark his answer as correct. But I'd still be interested, if anyone knows how long my original chips should last.

Comment: If we knew what's inside it we might be able to guess what could fail [first]... but even then it may a "primarily opinion based" answer. Since you haven't even told us what's inside... this is basically a consumer electronics [use] question... so off-topic. In general with keyboards, the electromechanical parts fail before any purely electronics parts do.

Comment: I'd tell you what's inside, but I'm out of the country, and need to have it shipped first. I'm mainly wondering what the average lifespan/shelf-life of the old chips are, in case they go bad, and I can't find replacements. It's very expensive to ship, so I want to make sure it's worth it. It's a really nice keyboard, so I'm hoping it'll work out.

Comment: Unless you do something rude to them, the chips should be fine for a long, long time. Capacitors, potentiometers, and poorly stress relieved input jacks are common failures IMPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine on pretty much any parts you find. I do know that electrolytic capacitors can dry out over a very long time, but I've never experienced that. Also most of the time, capacitors and resistors are too short to be worth salvaging. They can be bought at websites like mouser (personal favorite) and digikey for a couple cents in bulk. Also surface mount components I find aren't worth taking, but that shouldn't be a problem given the age of the keyboard. You can very well remove anything though and solder new wires to the terminals, if you want to spend the time. It's all fair game.

Comment: What do you mean by "surface mount components I find aren't worth taking"? Do you mean it's not worth taking parts off of other old keyboards? My biggest concern is the chips, and if I'll be able to find a replacement if I ever need one.

Comment: No, surface mount components are more modern and are incredibly tiny. Look inside any electronic device made in the last couple years and you will find itty bitty parts. Through hole components, are what you will find in the keyboard. They literally go through the board, with each side of the component soldered to contacts in each hole. The through hole components are perfectly fine to use.

Comment: Whoops, I seem to have misunderstood your question. The keyboard should work perfectly fine. If you need to replace the chips, you can look up the numbers online and find the parts. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Should I be able to find replacements for 25 year old chips? I'd open it up, and look at what chips are inside, but I'm out of the country, and I'm going to have it shipped to me. But first, I want to figure out if I'll be able to fix it, if a chip goes bad, since shipping this thing is going to be expensive.

Comment: Definitely. Most parts have been around for decades, very rarely do they get discontinued. If they do, there are almost certainly improvements that will do the same job.

Comment: Thanks! I love this keyboard, but I was worried it was too old to maintain. So now I can stop worrying:)

Answer (score 1):

Electrolytic capacitor failure is the most common problem in old electronic devices.  It is considered to be routine maintenance to replace all of the electrolytic caps when one or more has failed.

There are several failure modes but these capacitor failures are generally caused by the electrolyte drying out.  The failure modes most commonly seen are:

1) Loss of capacitance.  Problem shows up as hum (if the power supply reservoir cap has dried out) or as poor low-frequency response (coupling or bypass caps dropping in value).

2) High ESR.  Problems can be similar to the above but if the cap is used in a switch-mode power supply, all sorts of other problems can show up because the power supply rails are unstable.

There are many user groups on the Internet that discuss restoring old electronic devices, including vintage electronic musical instruments.  They will have much good advice for you.

Comment: This keyboard is pretty popular, so you're right, there should be a user group somewhere. And replacing capacitors doesn't seem difficult. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look on youtube found dead keys and dead LCD backlight in an A80: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njKXdzLzvPE

And dead keys in a similar model (A90): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iKyY5g77jY

That's basically how you find out this kind of info [as a consumer]... word of mouth, the 21st century version.

Comment: I did find a website with some spare parts, but I wasn't sure about the chips. Thanks for the advice.